Distributed redis cluster in podman
I have to create a redis cluster on a distributed system, using podman containers.
If I was allowed to use docker I would have been able to use docker swarm to link the daemons of the host machines, and then create a overlay network containing containers from both the machines, however there is no native support for swarming in podman, how do I go about creating a distributed redis cluster in this case.
P.s I have just started working with redis and containarization, so a comprehensive answer would be really appreciated!
Tried docker swarm, but apparently my orgnization has to use podman instead of docker!
